# Issue on setOnclickListener

Tags: android

I have two buttons set, "OK" and "Cancel" in main.xml. I have `setOnclickListener` for the **Cancel**. When I click on **OK** i need another xml file say abc.xml to get displayed. I have added that xml file under the layout folder.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your abc.xml is another `Activity`. What you need to do is:

- Create a class that extends `Activity`, for example Abc.
- In the `onCreate()` method call `setContentView(R.layout.abc.xml)`.
- Add the `Activity` to the `AndroidManifest` file.
- In the `OnClickListener` of the button, write:

  startActivity(new Intent(YouActivityWithTheButtons.this, Abc.class));